# Howto select multiple fields and aggregate (or rollup) on one

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to create a report across several joined tables as follows:

```
SELECT
  r.recipe_id "Recipe ID"
  ,r.name "Recipe Name"
  ,m.name "Meal Name"
  ,array_agg(distinct(bucket.name)) as "Plans"
  ,mn_sodium.meas_amt "Recipe Sodium"
  ,mn_cholesterol.meas_amt "Recipe Cholesterol"

FROM meals m

-- Join Recipes
INNER JOIN meals_recipe_xref mrx
  ON mrx.meal_id = m.meal_id
INNER JOIN recipes r
  ON r.recipe_id = mrx.recipe_id

-- Determine Plans
LEFT OUTER JOIN plans dmo
  ON dmo.meal_id = mrx.meal_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN calorie_buckets bucket
  ON bucket.bucket_id = dmo.bucket_id

-- Get sodium and cholesterol
LEFT OUTER JOIN recipe_nutrients mn_sodium
  ON mn_sodium.recipe_id = r.recipe_id
  AND mn_sodium.nutri_type_id = 64 -- sodium
LEFT OUTER JOIN recipe_nutrients mn_cholesterol
  ON mn_cholesterol.recipe_id = r.recipe_id
  AND mn_cholesterol.nutri_type_id = 26 -- cholesterol

GROUP BY
  r.name
  ,m.name
  ,r.recipe_id
  ,mn_sodium.meas_amt
  ,mn_cholesterol.meas_amt

ORDER BY m.name
```

...which gives me sodium and cholesterol amounts for each recipe in a given meal (a meal is comprised of potentially multiple recipes).

What is the best way to rollup those sodium and cholesterol values for each meal and duplicate those in the report?

I've tried to use `GROUPING SETS`, but no joy. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want the sum of values of `mn_sodium.meas_amt` and `mn_cholesterol.meas_amt` per `m.name`. As you want the same resulting values in a set of rows partitioned by `m.name`, you can simple use [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html), being `m.name` the `PARTITION BY`:

```
SELECT
  r.recipe_id "Recipe ID"
  ,r.name "Recipe Name"
  ,m.name "Meal Name"
  ,array_agg(distinct(bucket.name)) as "Plans"
  ,mn_sodium.meas_amt "Recipe Sodium"
  ,mn_cholesterol.meas_amt "Recipe Cholesterol"
  ,sum(mn_sodium.meas_amt) OVER(PARTITION BY m.name) AS "Meal Sodium"
  ,sum(mn_cholesterol.meas_amt) OVER(PARTITION BY m.name) "Meal Cholesterol"
FROM
...
```

Another syntax you could use is naming the window apart for reuse:

```
SELECT
  r.recipe_id "Recipe ID"
  ,r.name "Recipe Name"
  ,m.name "Meal Name"
  ,array_agg(distinct(bucket.name)) as "Plans"
  ,mn_sodium.meas_amt "Recipe Sodium"
  ,mn_cholesterol.meas_amt "Recipe Cholesterol"
  ,sum(mn_sodium.meas_amt) OVER w_meal AS "Meal Sodium"
  ,sum(mn_cholesterol.meas_amt) OVER w_meal "Meal Cholesterol"
FROM
...
WINDOW w_meal AS (PARTITION BY m.name)
```

Comment: Simply fantastic! Exactly what I needed. I figured there was a way. Thank you!